# Best way to organize singleton with virtual methods

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm working on simple framework written on C++. Now i have something like

**app.cpp**

```
#include "app.h"

namespace App
{

}

void App::init()
{

}

void App::timerEvent(int time)
{

}
```

But what if i don't want to listen to timerEvent in some cases? I still have to write empty method implementation.

My idea is to move from namespace to `class App : public BaseApp` with `virtual void BaseApp::init() = 0` and `virtual void BaseApp::timerEvent(int time) {}` in `BaseApp` (similary to Qt `QApplication`). However App should be singleton then, but i don't see any way to specify it from `BaseApp`, so i have to write singleton code in `App` and all virtual idea makes no sense.

How should i design it?

P.S. I don't want to use listeners here. It seems like overkill for me.

P.P.S. I need singleton because i initialize app instance from `main`, but still want to access its methods from another classes.

Comment: I don't understand everything, but in any case, just don't use a Singleton and design your architecture based on that principle.

Comment: You can *choose* to create only **one** `App` object. You don't need a singleton to make that choice.

Comment: @Galik but i don't see any another possibility. I want to call my app instance methods from another code parts.

Comment: @Ximik Dependency injection is one possibility. Just pass a reference to your `App` to any functions or objects that need to call its member functions.

Comment: @JosephThomson ye, good idea, thanks

Comment: You could add a template parameter to your singleton's `instance()` method and pass your specific application type as a template parameter. A `static_assert()` can be used to ensure the template parameter is a derived type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate virtual functions inside your namespace with function pointer or std::function. Just make something like this:

```
#include "app.h"

namespace App
{
    std::function<void(int)> vtTimerEvent;
}

void App::timerEventImpl(int time)
{
    // default timerEvent implementation
}

void App::init(std::function<void(int)> timerEvent = &App::timerEventImpl)
{
    vtTimerEvent = timerEvent;
}

void App::timerEvent(int time)
{
   vtTimerEvent(time);
}
```

This is not very great design, but it does what you want.

**UPDATE**

Another approximation:

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

// virtual base interface
class IInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~IInterface() = 0;
};

IInterface::~IInterface(){} // must have

// virtual App interface
class IApp :
    virtual public IInterface
{
public:
    virtual void init() = 0;
    virtual void timerEvent(int time) = 0;
};


// static App interface
class App
{
private:
    ~App(); // nobody can create an instance
public:
    static void init(const std::shared_ptr<IApp> &impl_p)
    {
        if (!impl)
        {
            impl = impl_p;
            impl->init();
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Already initialized");
        }
    }

    static void timerEvent(int time)
    {
        impl->timerEvent(time);
    }
private:
    static std::shared_ptr<IApp> impl;
};

std::shared_ptr<IApp> App::impl;

// specific App implementation
class AppImplementation1 :
    public IApp
{
    //...
};


int main(int, char**)
{
    auto myImpl = std::make_shared<AppImplementation1>();
    App::init(myImpl);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```